# Disk quota not getting set in APFS file system (MacBook Pro, macOS High Sierra (10.13))

Tags: macos, high-sierra, apfs

I tried enabling quota on a file system(type APFS) mounted using this command `quotaon /dev/disk1s1` but it throws: /dev/disk1s1/ not found in fstab.  Previously it used to work in HFS type file system.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What command did you issue to enable quotas? What’s the end goal?

Comment: I tried using  `quotaon` command to enable disk quota, the end goal is to restrict disk usage for certain users.